# How to install old version of 'Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse'?

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

After I updated 'Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse' from version 4.1.6 to version 4.1.7 (and Vaadin Designer from 4.6.18 to 4.6.20) something broke.
I started to get constant error when oppened Vaadin design (LitTamplate) java file:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Requesting Java AST from selection".
'boolean com.ibm.icu.text.UTF16.isSurrogate(char)'
```

This error does not happen when using Eclipse 2022-12 with Vaadin Plug-in 4.1.7 and Vaadin Designer 4.6.20.
But there is other issues there:
https://github.com/vaadin/designer/issues/2443

I was using Eclipse 2021-12 with 'Vaadin Plug-in for Eclipse' 4.1.6 and 'Vaadin Designer' 4.6.18 before update. Now I can not install old versions back into the Eclipse.

Vaadin plugin guide will always offer only the latest version.
https://vaadin.com/eclipse

It would be nice to have version links for installing older versions.
Something like this:
https://vaadin.com/eclipse/2021-12/plugin/4.1.6/designer/4.6.18

Comment: The problem seems to be that the Vaadin Designer does not yet work with m2e 2.x (which contains some breaking API changes compared to m2e 1.x) which is included in Eclipse since 2022-09. I guess only a few adjustments are needed. So how about a pull request with this few adjustments to move Vaadin Designer forward instead of spending time sticking to the past?

Comment: Yes it would be best if I could always use latest code, but ...
This is not first time that latest Vaadin code is not working either with latest Eclipse or any of older ones :(

So it would be nice to be able to install Eclipse/Vaadin combination that is know to work. While waiting for fix.

Comment: What prevents you to create a pull request for those few adjustments?

Comment: Few reasons :) 
No code, no knowledge how, no time, etc. 
Your question should be directed at Vaadin devs :)

Comment: If you don't want to fix it yourself and if you don't think it's worth paying someone else to fix it, your options are either use Eclipse 2022-06 as it is or Eclipse 2022-12 with m2e 1.x instead of 2.x.